# git config color shading

Tags: git, powershell

I am using git 2.24.0 with powershell

And I have noticed that all the colors as defined in .gitconfig
are overly dark shaded
also what is supposed to be yellow is white
and white is grey.
In the screen shot i have tested all colors with

[color "branch"] remote

but the display is too dark with all colors except yellow (which is white)
Is there any solution to use colors in git besides defining everything as Yellow/White ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors that are being used here are defined by your terminal, which in this case is the default terminal used with PowerShell.  There are a couple options:

1. You can [adjust the terminal colors](https://beebom.com/how-change-powershell-color-scheme-windows-10/).
2. If the terminal supports it, you can use a numeric color from 0-255 instead of a color name in Git, using one of the [colors from the XTerm 256 color chart](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/).  Those provide a richer set of colors to choose from.